# What is the difference between nützlich and sinnvoll?

Tags: difference, word-choice, adjective

What is the difference between the two adjectives "nützlich" and "sinnvoll", when both of them mean "useful"? Could you please give some examples?

Comment: More or less the same as the difference between useful/beneficial and meaningful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As often in German, you can to split those two words into their pieces and analyze what they are about:

> nützlich — es ist von Nutzen → it's of benefit/advantage
>
> sinnvoll — es ist voller Sinn → it's full of reason

Most times, things that are full of reason tend to be beneficial so you can use those two words interchangably. There is a difference about plan and outcome, however:

> Mein Plan ist sinnvoll. – Gut.
>
> Mein Plan ist nützlich. – Wofür?
>
> Dieser sinnvolle Plan war sehr nützlich. – Gut.
>
> Dieser nützliche Plan war sehr sinnvoll. – Hä?

A fixed phrase you may encounter:

> Mach dich mal nützlich! *(Come on, help us!)*